# Impartiality axiom in Terry Tao's Arrow's Theorem proof

Tags: proof-explanation, social-choice-theory

The short expository paper is [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/arrow.pdf).
On page 2,

> The notion of a quorum is well-defined; it is not possible for such a group to be able to force a vote some of the time and not at other times because this would contradict the independence axiom. **Also, it doesn't matter who $A$ and $B$ are becase of the impartiality axiom.**

I don't quite understand the bolded setence. Also, what difference would it make to the proof if we don't assume the impartiality axiom?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bolded sentence means that if a group $G$ of voters is a quorum for one pair of candidates, then $G$ is a quorum for every pair of candidates. Specifically, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are candidates, and $G$ is a quorum for the pair $\langle A,B\rangle$. This means that if everyone in $G$ votes $A$ ahead of $B$, and everyone not in $G$ votes $B$ ahead of $A$, then the voting system places $A$ ahead of $B$. Now let $C$ and $D$ be any two candidates; impartiality means that the voting system treats the pair $\langle C,D\rangle$ exactly as it treats the pair $\langle A,B\rangle$, so if everyone in $G$ votes $C$ ahead of $D$, and everyone not in $G$ votes $D$ ahead of $C$, then the voting system places $C$ ahead of $D$. In other words, $G$ is also a quorum for the pair $\langle C,D\rangle$.

If this were not the case, the notion of *quorum* would not be well-defined: we might even have a group $G$ of voters who were a quorum for $\langle A,B\rangle$ but not for $\langle B,A\rangle$! That is it might happen that if everyone in $G$ votes $A$ ahead of $B$, and everyone not in $G$ votes $B$ ahead of $A$, then the voting system places $A$ ahead of $B$, but the voting system also places $A$ ahead of $B$ if everyone in $G$ votes $B$ ahead of $A$, and everyone not in $G$ votes $A$ ahead of $B$.

The rest of the argument depends on the fact that the notion of *quorum* is well-defined, so that a quorum for one pair of candidates is a quorum for every pair.

Comment: I don't quiet get the sense of Tao's impatiality axiom either. Causz' it seems that there is a Spread of Decisiveness lemma says that if G is decisive over any pair {x,y}, then G is [globally] decisive (e.g. in Sen's https://econweb.ucsd.edu/~rstarr/113Winter2012/Sen's%20ARRO-COL%2009A.pdf). Why does Tao assum this "axiom"? Maybe because that makes you need not to prove the lemma? And a proof following Tao's but without impartiality: https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/ashvin/files/arrow-theorem.pdf

Comment: @AnduinWilde: Tao actually answers your question in the PDF linked by the OP. Near the top of page 2 he says: *We remark that the impartiality axiom is not needed for Arrow’s theorem, but makes the proof simpler.* He goes on to invite the reader to find a proof that does not use impartiality, noting that one will have to deal with separate notions of quorum for each pair of candidates. This is exactly what Swaminathan has done in his section 3.1.